# Old picture is not deleted when retaking a picture

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

When I take a picture everything works fine. The pic is made and I see it afterwards on the page. When I click to retake the pic I can do it, but now come the problem. The old picture is placed under the first picture Ive taken. I know that bc I can see a little bit of my 2. picture laying under my first picture. To see my second picture I have take a 3. picture (second time retake picture) Now the first pic is deleted, the 2. pic is on the top and the 3. is placed under the 2. pic. How can I achieve that the pic is directly deleted when I retake a picture?

```
export class PostPage {
  public photos: any;
  public base64Image: string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private camera: Camera) {

  }




  ngOnInit(){
    this.photos = [];
  }

  ionViewDidEnter(){                    //Damit Kamera automatisch öffent
   const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 100,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
}


this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
 // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
 // If it's base64:
 this.base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
  this.photos.push(this.base64Image);
  this.photos.reverse();


}, (err) => {
 // Handle error
});
  }
cancel(){


    const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 100,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
}



this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
 // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
 // If it's base64:
 this.base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
  this.photos.push(this.base64Image);
  this.photos.reverse();


}, (err) => {
 // Handle error
});
  }

}
```